# How to Play Video from a url?

Tags: xaml, windows-8.1, mediaelement

I am developing a Windows 8.1 app and I'd like to play a video from a URL.

I tried this but it is not working

```
<MediaElement x:Name="VideoPlayer"
        Height="425"
        Width="700"
        AreTransportControlsEnabled="True"
        Source="http://www.dailymotion.com/video/x16xp80_brain-games-what-you-don-t-know_shortfilms"
        AutoPlay="False"
        DoubleTapped="VideoPlayer_DoubleTapped" />
```

Answer (score 1):

This not working because your url is a web page. You must set uri of [supported video file](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh986969.aspx).

Comment: @Nguyen-how can I do that?

Comment: They have API to get video url: https://developer.dailymotion.com/documentation#video

Comment: and what if I want to play videos from other websites?